# Restarted droplet and got error Class 'MongoClient' not found

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5, sudo, digital-ocean

For some reasons I restarted Digital Ocean droplet and i got error `Class 'MongoClient' not found`, I'm using Laravel.
 Updated sudo but the same error. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mongo extension for php.

```
pecl install mongo
```

Comment: I have installed it before restart. I need install it again?

Comment: Have you correctly enabled the extension before restart?
Run php -m | grep mongo to see if it enlists there.